# Determining local horizon using USGS topographical data?

Tags: elevation

Using USGS' topographical data (DEM), you can determine what your 
local horizon looks like. Has anyone done this?

Example: if the packet of land 50 feet away from you has a 10 foot 
higher elevation, it will subtend a horizon-blocking angle of 11.31 
degrees (the arctangent of 10 feet over 50 feet).

The horizon-blocking topography isn't always adjacent: a large 
mountain several miles away may block more of your horizon than nearby 
topography. Caveats:

- For more distant items, you'd also have to compensate for the Earth's 
  curvature.
- USGS only measures *average* elevation for a *packet* of land, so the 
  results will be approximate.
- The results also won't include man-made structures, trees, or other 
  non-topographical elements.
- Our eyes are ~4-5 feet above ground level, and you'd have to compensate for that.

Nonetheless, this all seems quite do-able, so I'm guessing someone has 
done it?

Answer (score 0):

noted that no one has responded. i've been casually interested in how one could determine a local horizon, and found your question. a bit of Google helped discover the following quite useful URL, http://www.gitta.info/TerrainAnalyi/en/html/VisibilAppls_learningObject6.html, brought to us by the Geographic Information Technology Trainiing Alliance